# prove that $fp(1 - x) = 1 - \chi_{\Bbb Z}(x) - fp(x)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

prove that $fp(1 - x) = 1 - \chi_{\Bbb Z}(x) - fp(x)$, where $fp(x) = x - \lfloor x\rfloor$, and $0 \le fp(x) < 1$, and $\chi_{\Bbb Z}$ is the characteristic function of the integers

By the way of contradiction assume $fp(1-x) \ne 1 - \chi_{\Bbb Z}(x) - fp(x)$.  suppose $x \in\Bbb Z$; then $\chi_{\Bbb Z}(x) = 1$, and $fp(x) = 0$, since $0 \le fp(x) < 1$, and $x$ is an integer.  so $$fp(1-x) = 1-1-0 = 0\;.$$  But $fp(1-x)$ ... i am lost here

can someone help me on this.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: I would suggest that you use cases, either $x$ is an integer or it is not (observe that $x$ is an integer iff $1-x$ is an integer - requires proof).

Case 1: If $x$ is an integer, then $fp(x)=0=fp(1-x)$, and you can check the formula easily in that case.

Case 2: If $x$ is not an integer, then we can write $x=n+y$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $0<y<1$.  In this case, $fp(x)=y$ and $fp(1-x)=1-y$ (check this).